# NGINX - redirect to a custom maintenance page without changing url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a NGINX server running, now I have the following directive and location block for a custom 503 error page:

```
error_page 503 @maintenance;
location @maintenance {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}
```

When a user is redirected to the custom 503 error page, the url in his browser changes to the following:

```
https://www.example.com/maintenance
```

I would like the user to be redirected to the maintenance but keep the root domain in the address bar:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: Have you tried to use `last` instead of `break` ?

Comment: If `maintenance.html` is in your document root, you should use `try_files /maintenance.html =404;`

Comment: @IVOGELOV thank you! this solved my problem!